# Web Scraping with Selenium: not knowing where the text is coming from

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website using Selenium and Python.
I want to extract a specific text from a specific page. I successfully navigated to the page, but selenium always returns an empty list when I attempt any of the following:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id()
driver.find_elements_by_class()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name()
```

And many other methods(As well as the singular version of them).
I also suspected it being a data loading problem and I added an implicit wait, which still results in an empty list.

This is the  in the HTML when I inspect the element:

```html
    <textarea style="width: 658px; height: 128px; overflow: auto;" autocomplete="off" id="ContentPH_description" name="ContentPH_description" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="false" aria-multiline="true" class="x-form-textarea x-form-field vms-viewmode-view-set" readonly="" aria-labelledby="ContentPH_description_label" title="" aria-invalid="false" maxlength="10000" oldindex="0" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
```

I also tried looking for the parent tag of that tag up there and the same results.

Help. I would like to retrieve the text inside the `<textarea>`.

Comment: The HTML you've shown says there's no text inside that tag so what value are you expecting to get?

Comment: You've shown just a start tag, some attributes, and an end tag.

Comment: can you share a link to the web page or the entire page HTML? The presented single element HTML is not enough

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, That's where my confusion comes in. I can see the text on the web page, and that's the tag I get directed to when I hit inspect the element.

Comment: @Prophet, Can't. needs a login for you to reach that point. Any specific HTML you're looking for that I might be able to provide?

Comment: As I can see from what you have shared this element attributes aren't unique so we have to catch some unique dependence with some parent elements. Also possible we should get the text from other element,not this one.

Comment: @Prophet Where do you suggest I start looking?

Comment: Look, I'm not really prophet :) To say that I have to see the entire page HTML. It should be unique expression matching that element only. Also, you should use stable attributes only.

Comment: Have you tried *waiting* for the text first?

Comment: Or use DevTools to search for the text and see which element actually contains the text you want. You may be right-clicking on the wrong element.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have done that, and it routed me towards a <script>  tag. What do I do from here?

Comment: Cannot really help you further without a URL. It would be like the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Try adding an explicit wait (e.g., `time.sleep(10)`) before you do `driver.find_element_by_id(...)`. Again, without the URL, I'd be just guessing.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel providing a URL means I need to provide you with a log in so that you'll be able to access what I am accessing. It's like trying to scrape your Direct messages on Instagram or Facebook. Not only that, you can't simply make a fake account to help me, you'd need access from someone already on the website to be able to get an account.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have a 20-second implicit wait right before the find element method.

Comment: I have a (web element variable of the script tag).get_attribute('innerHTML'), but it's returning nothing as well. What do you recommend?

Comment: I'll be wasting my time and yours without the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just use the methods without pointing them at something, I'll use the id on this one
Use find element by Id

```
description =  driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPH_description" )
```

if you alternatively use find elements which is more you need to index the list like so

```
description =  driver.find_elements_by_id("ContentPH_description" )[0]
```

Comment: Forgive me for not being clear, but I did indeed point them at the ID, the class, and class name of it, and of its parent tag.
It will either return an empty line or it would return an "Unable to locate element" error.

Comment: You missed the `s` in your 2nd example.